# Restore C# Windows Forms backcolor

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a button on a Windows Forms form for which I change the background color to `Color.Yellow` when it's clicked. When it's clicked again I want to restore it to the original default appearance.

The default backcolor is `SystemColor.Control`.

When the button is clicked the first time the only thing I change is the

```
btn.Text = "ABC";
btn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

When it's clicked again I do

```
btn.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
```

The new background does not have the same shading as it originally did before any clicks. The button originally had a background that was not a solid color, but was two slightly different shades of grey. The final color ends up being a solid shade of grey.

I'm testing this on a Windows 7 machine.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  Also, what OS version are you running on?

Comment: The more effort you put in your questions, the better answers you'll get so include screenshots of the problem.

Comment: Related: *[How to reset to default button BackColor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569200)*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (button1.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
{
    button1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
}
else
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You should also set UseVisualStyleBackColor to true. This property gets set to false when you change the backcolor.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `btn.ResetBackColor()` instead of manually setting the `BackColor`.

Comment: That function doesn't exist in the winform button (at least in a .net 3.5 winform)

Comment: It actually does exist, it just doesn't show up in intellisense because it's marked as [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]

Comment: @JonF According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbackcolor.aspx) it exists, since .Net 1.0

Comment: My bad.  Unfortunately I get the same result with that

Answer (score 1):

This will restore the default look (tested on Windows 7, .net 3.5):

```
btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```