# I have two buttons in my activity, clicking the two of them should unhighlight the other one

Tags: c#

I have two buttons in my activity, clicking any of the two of them should unhighlight the other one. The result on my work is both of them are highlighted.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button4.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Based on that code, I'd expect it to work just like you described.  What did you try to do to get the results you want?

Comment: The result that I want mate is, if im going to click the button 3 it should be highlighted and if im going to click the button 4 it should be highlighted this will trigger that if im going to click the button 4 the highlighted button 3 should not be highlighted.

Comment: Ive done some solutions but it wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the other button to its default `BackColor` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569200/how-to-reset-to-default-button-backcolor)

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
    button4.BackColor = default(Color);
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button4.BackColor = Color.Red;
    button3.BackColor = default(Color);
}
```