# In Vb.net,could not get the default style of a button after changing Backcolor of a Button

Tags: vb.net, button

In Vb.net, i changed the button backcolor on mousehover event, but on mouseleave event  i cannot change the color of button to standard style. Button is looking in full silver color and missing the usual glossy look

On Mousehover event i gave Button1.BackColor = Color.Orange and on Mouseleave event i gave Button1.BackColor = Color.Silver , but could not get the default style of a button. 
Wat to do to get back the default style of button?

Comment: i am working in Winforms..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore c# winform backcolor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218144/restore-c-sharp-winform-backcolor) It is the same question just different language. Just set the Button's UsevisualStyleBackColor to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Button1.MouseEnter** will not make the button color change until mouse is steady over the button, while using **Button1.MouseHover** will change the button color when the color mouse just hovers over the button.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'AddHandler Button1.MouseEnter, AddressOf btn1MouseHover
    AddHandler Button1.MouseHover, AddressOf btn1MouseHover
    AddHandler Button1.MouseLeave, AddressOf btn1MouseLeave
End Sub

Private Sub btn1MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn1MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```